# Google Relatime API stops responding after computer wakes up from sleep mode

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Easy to reproduce:

1. Go to https://realtime-cube.appspot.com
2. start a new game
3. Open a second tab with the same game
4. Make sure that both tabs are realtime connected upon change.
5. Now, put your computer (in my case Mac OSX) in a sleep mode for 4 seconds (in my case just close it and re-open it).
6. Go back to the game tabs and make a change
7. The tabs are not sync with each other. All changes are not saved in document.
8. Errors are not thrown during a save operation.

Any explanation? Should I reload the document at this point? How should I catch this situation?

Comment: This question is similar to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415183/google-drive-realtime-api-oauth2-refresh-errors-part-3

Comment: What browser are you using?  I'm unable to reproduce this in chrome.

Comment: Thanks Cheryl, I am using Chrome, MacOSX. I double checked with a co-worker, he experienced the same issue.

Comment: Hi ganoro, I've been seeing the same thing on my end for the last week or two as well and have been trying to get a simplified repro. I have only seen this issue when the computer is asleep when the OAuth token expires and needs to be renewed. The issue has been reported to me on iPhone 4/5 7.1 devices, and I can reproduce in app consistently with chrome on osx.

Comment: Same here on our side! token_refresh_required is fired after some time of inactivity and we can't revalidate it.